# How to customize my UITableView cell as below

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

[image]

Am using custom tableview cell in my code. Please can anybody help me how to write the code for common friends cell. How can i get the names AMANDA,VIKA LEVINA,NATASHA,KATE,JESICA names in rectangular box.

Comment: you could use an `UICollectionView` within the `UITableViewCell`...

Comment: Please can you suggest me how to use UICollectionView within the UITableView as per my requirement.

Answer (score 4):

For common friends and Facebook interest cells you can use UICollectionView and adjust cell width depends upon text otherwise you can use one of below listed controls.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jctaglistview

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/taglistview

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/antagsview

Comment: Am working in objective-c language.Am not able to get the output as per my requirement.Can anybody suggest me>Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you have to design two custom cells in your IB first for image view cell and other for list given below in your cell. create two custom cell in IB and design them according to your need and after that in your cell for row at index path method differentiate between these cell like:

```
uitablviewCell *cell;
if(indexPath.row == 0)
{
        cell = [tableview dequereusablecellWithIdentifier:Firstcell];
}
else
{
       cell  = [tableview dequereusablecellWithIdentifier:secondCell];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For common friends and Facebook interest cells, You can use [ANTagsView](https://github.com/adnan-careaxiom/ANTagsView).

Using this, You can get tag view which you are showing in image.
So this view, you can add into your cell. For tags view, you have to pass array according to your view.

And set height of cell dynamically using `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method.

After that, you can get your view.

Comment: I used  ANTagsView code for common friends and Facebook interest cells.Am not able decrease the font size of AMANDA characters.Please can you guide for this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yess you can change font size from 'addTagInView' method from 'ANTagsView.m' file. Also If you want to set label border, then you have to add 'tagLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor purpleColor].CGColor;
    tagLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;' this code into 'addTagInView' method in 'ANTagsView.m' file.

Comment: If you want any changes, then directly change it into that ANTagsView Code.

Comment: yes,i changed code alot but am not able to decrease the font size.Any help for that.

Comment: Then what issue are facing ?? If you have spacing issue then change values of the 'TAG_SPACE_HORIZONTAL', 'TAG_SPACE_VERTICAL' variables. And if you have width or height issue, then change the value of 'tagLabel.frame' into 'addTagInView' method in 'ANTagsView.m' file.

Comment: Am getting all labels width same.I need as per number of characters my labels width should increase and decrease.

Comment: Then change the values of 'MAX_TAG_SIZE', 'MIN_TAG_SIZE'. And if you want to label's width as per number of characters, then pass different values in array of tags like this. " NSArray *tagsToDisplay = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"AMANDA", @"VIKA LEVINA", @"NATASHA", @"KATE", @"JESICA", nil];
    ANTagsView *tagsView = [[ANTagsView alloc] initWithTags:tagsToDisplay frame:CGRectMake(10, 130, screenRect.size.width - 10, 10)]; ". Then you have to get dynamic label.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95338/discussion-between-vinathy-nvr-and-meet-doshi).